# Cannot read property - displayWith

Tags: angular

When I select a suggested Offer from the autocomplete list I get this error:

[image]

I thought `displayWith` is just used to display the string of the items, not sure how `name` property was accessed when it is undefined and why the error only occurred when I select an item in the list. However, I don't have any functionality issues, its just giving me errors in the browser's console.

new-offer-form.component.ts:

```
...
foodItemName(offer?: Offer): string | undefined {
    return offer ? offer.foodItem.name : undefined;
}
...
```

new-offer-form.component.html:

```
...
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="foodItemName" (optionSelected)='assign($event.option.value)'>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let offer of filteredOffers$ | async" [value]="offer">{{ offer.foodItem.name }}</mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
...
```

Comment: Did you double check that your offer always has a foodItem set on it? That error seems to be saying that the property is undefined right there.

Comment: Yes it does, I checked that each Offer object has a foodItem in the Chrome console.

Comment: Did you console.log the offer and then expand it to see the foodItem property or did you log the offer.foodItem property instead? I ask this because it is often an issue people run into where they log an object and expect the object in the console to be the object at the time it was logged to the console, but it isn't. The properties that show up when it is expanded is what exists in the object at the moment it was first expanded, not logged.

Comment: Maybe this one could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162076/material-angular-io-mat-autocomplete-displaywith-function-update-scope-variabl/54534922#54534922

Answer (score 4):

Your scope goes undefined inside `[displayWith]="foodItemName"` !

Replace it with `[displayWith]="foodItemName.bind(this)"`