# Angular 6 service undefined after constructor initialization

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-services, angular-cli-v6

I have a service (ClientProfileService) injected into my component via the constructor, like so:

```
import { ClientProfileService } from '@app/services/client-profile/client-profile.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-transaction',
  templateUrl: './add-transaction.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-transaction.component.scss']
})
export class AddTransactionComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

... 
...

constructor(
   private clientProfileService: ClientProfileService
) { }

...
...

public autoCompleteDisplay(clientId?: string): string | undefined {
    if (clientId && clientId.trim() !== '') {

      // next line produces the error
      let profile: IDetailedClientProfile = this.clientProfileService.findClientProfile(clientId);

      if (profile) {
        return profile.ClientName;
      }
    }
    return undefined;
  }
}
```

I'm using an Angular Material Autocomplete component in my template using the [displayWith] attribute as explained [in the Angular Material documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#setting-separate-control-and-display-values).  Whenever I select a value in the dropdown box, the selected value (clientId) is passed to the 'autoCompleteDisplay' function.  That part is working fine and 'autoCompleteDisplay' is being called when I want it to.

ClientProfileService is defined like so:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn:'root'
})
export class ClientProfileService {
  private teamClientListSubject: BehaviorSubject<IDetailedClientProfile[]> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  constructor(
      private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  public findClientProfile(clientId: string): IDetailedClientProfile {
    let profile: IDetailedClientProfile = this.teamClientListSubject.value.filter(x => x.ClientId === clientId)[0];
    return profile;
  }
}
```

I have referenced the BehaviorSubject in the service in multiple components and even other functions that return observables with no problems, which I left out in this case to keep the post more readable.

When the 'autoCompleteDisplay' function is called, I receive an error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'findClientProfile' of undefined
```

So ClientProfileService is undefined in the component at this particular point, but why?  I've initialized this service in several other areas in the app using this exact same method with no issues.

Comment: just curious did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope - I am using a workaround at this time until I have time to come back and look at it again.

Comment: I think this can help you: [Angular2 component's “this” is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38245450/).

Answer (score 0):

I think your import is wrong, it should be

```
import { ClientProfileService } from './services/client-profile/client-profile.service';
```

Comment: I think this seems reasonable. @app is a webpack-alias right? Then I'd assume fiddling with webpacks node-options for __dirname / __filename could make a difference as well.  https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/

Comment: Thanks for the response - the import path is correct though. The path is an alias set up in tsconfig.json.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try to register the service in the AppModule

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your service is added to the providers in app.module.ts:

```
import { ClientProfileService } from '@app/services/client-profile/client-profile.service';
...
@NgModule({ 
  declarations: [ ... ],
  imports: [ ... ],
  providers: [ ..., ClientProfileService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent] 
}) export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer you need can be found here: [Cannot read property - displayWith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49091255/cannot-read-property-displaywith). 
Problem is the way you used displayWith and not the injection on the .ts files.